# How do I go about replacing the LCD on my 2014 macbook air?

Tags: macbook-pro, repair

I have a macbook air which recently began showing the "lines of death" up and down my screen, a common sign of damage to the LCD panel. I can still login and to an extent use the machine, with the exception of doing so blindly. The model number is A1446, and it is a 13 in. screen. How do I go about making this repair myself at home? Or would it be more worth my time (and nicer to my wallet) to get it fixed at a store or other repair center?

**NOTE:**
I essentially need the repair completed within 24 hours as this machine is a critical part of my work

Also, I dont know the cause of the damage exactly, i went to bed with everything A-OK, and in the morning the LCD wasnt working properly.

Answer (score 2):

> I essentially need the repair completed within 24 hours

If you need to ask, you do not have the necessary skills, parts and tools to repair it in that time frame.

Also unlikely any service centre can turn it around in 24 hours.

So your options are:

1. Get an external monitor. The condition of the internal screen then becomes irrelevant.
2. Buy a new one, copy your data with Migration Assistant.

Given that the screen is typically the most expensive sub-component, and requires near total disassembly to change, you need to decide between the high repair cost to get an old machine back, or a bit more to get a brand new one with warranty, bigger storage etc. etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you did this at home, you would void your warranty and have a bigger chance of messing something else up.

It might not be as cheap as fixing it yourself, but you have less of a chance of destroying your MacBook if you go to an Apple store and get it fixed. [Here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/27114650#message27114650) is how to schedule an Apple store appointment.